# Computing a conditional expectation for uniform RVs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X_1, ..., X_n \sim U[0, 1]$ are iid uniform RVs. How would I go about computing $E[X_n | X_{(n)}]$ where $X_{(n)}$ is the nth order statistic, i.e. $\max\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$ ?

I'm stuck without any ideas on this.

Comment: "I'm stuck without any ideas on this." This is odd... Did you try to solve the case $n=2$, for example?

Answer (score 3):

A joint independent uniform distribution remains "flat" even after conditioning on what region the values lie in. Thus, your conditional expectation is $c/n + ((n-1)/n)E(Y_c)$ where $c$ is the observed maximum value (which could have been $X_n$), and $Y_c$ is the uniform random variable restricted to $[0,c]$. Thus your conditional expectation is $c/n + ((n-1)/n)c/2$, where $c$ is the given maximum of the $n$ samples.

Comment: You can think of this as an application of the total expectation formula: $E[X_n|X_{(n)}=x]=E[X_n|X_n=x]P(X_n=X_{(n)})+E[X_n|X_n<x]P(X_n<X_{(n)})$.

Comment: Answer says $(n + 1)/2n X_{(n)}$ which is close to what you have, is the answer wrong then?

Comment: Should $E(Y_c)$ be $\frac{n-1}{n}E(Y_c)$ perhaps?

Comment: @Ian Thanks! I've never heard of this formula, is there a general form somewhere?

Comment: @MickA Yes you're right, i'll update

Answer (score -2):

Assume $Y = X_{(n)}.$ The pdf of $Y$ is $f(y) = ny^{n-1}$.  The joint pdf of $Y$ and $X_n$ is 
$$
f(y,x_n)= \begin{cases} x_n^{n-1}\delta(y-x_n) & x_n = y\\ (n-1)y^{n-2} & x_n < y \end{cases}
$$
The conditional pdf of $X_n$ given $Y$ is
$$
f(x_n/y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x_n^{n-1}}{ny^{n-1}}\delta(y-x_n) & x_n = y\\ \frac{(n-1)}{ny} & x_n < y \end{cases}
$$
So we have
$$
E[X_n/Y] = \frac{n+1}{2n}Y
$$